# What happens with the original numpy array when calling OpenCV functions?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, memory

I have been trying to speed up my computer vision code and ran into a problem. If I use an OpenCV function, which primarily stores its data in a numpy array, the output is a new array of a determined size, usually the same size as the source image. I understand that if I chose that name to be something other than the source that I now have two different arrays, but what happens if I name it the same thing? For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('IMG_1478.jpg', 1)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
dilation = np.ones((10, 10), "uint8")
img = cv2.dilate(img, dilation)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I'm still creating a copy of the array, I'm assuming I then have two different arrays at different memory addresses but with the same string values. Is that correct? If so, is there any way in python to delete the original image without deleting the new image? Similar to what I could do in C? I understand I could just use a different name so I can delete the original, I'm just posing the problem like I am so I can better understand the methods of memory allocation with python and opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img = cv2.dilate(img, dilation)` will create a new array and rebind the name `img` to it. If the ref count of the old array became zero, then the old array pointed by `img` will be release.

If you don't want `dilate()` create new array, you can pass an array object to the `dst` argument.